# Cancelling via ignoring a WCF call

Tags: .net, wcf, asynchronous, task-parallel-library

I'm trying to implement cancellation on the client side of a WCF call. I've seen a number of questions about cancelling the server process, but I don't need to do that. I have a UI that needs to respond to cancelling a long-running server-side process.

So I have the following code:

```
Const WayLongerThanItShouldEverTakeMilliseconds As Integer = 60 * 30 * 1000
Public Async Function CallService(token as CancellationToken) As Task(Of ReturnType)
    Dim client As IWcfService = _service
    Dim returnTask As Task(Of ReturnType) = client.FunctionAsync()
    Dim cancellationTask as Task = Task.Delay(WayLongerThanItShouldEverTakeMilliseconds, token).
       ContinueWith(Function(t) Task.FromCanceled(token), TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnCanceled)

    Await Task.WhenAny(returnTask, cancellationTask)
    token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()
    Return Await returnTask
End Function
```

It seems to work. I don't like the server effects, though the client is more important here. Is there some race case that I'm missing? I haven't seen anything like this floating around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works as is. It is a common approach to isolate and ignore operations that cannot be cancelled. I don't quite get what you are trying to do with the `cancellationTask.ContinueWith`. Seems not required.

Note, that you have a resource leak: Many `Delay` tasks may accumulate and end up doing nothing. Consider cancelling the delay task after the `WhenAny` task has completed. That frees up the internal resources (a timer).

I found it useful to package up all of this logic into a reusable helper method. That way you can easily create a proxy task for any other task. You can then instantly cancel anything if you're OK with the actual operation continuing.

---

**Edit:** Added extensions for future users:

```
<Extension()>
Public Async Function ToIgnorableTask(Of T)(originalTask As Task(Of T), token As CancellationToken) As Task(Of T)
    Using internalCts As New CancellationTokenSource()
        Using combinedCts As CancellationTokenSource = CancellationTokenSource.CreateLinkedTokenSource(token, internalCts.Token)
            Try
                Dim cancellationTask As Task = task.Delay(-1, combinedCts.Token)
                Await Task.WhenAny(originalTask, cancellationTask)
                token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()
                Return Await originalTask
            Finally
                internalCts.Cancel()
            End Try
        End Using
    End Using
End Function

<Extension()>
Public Async Function ToIgnorableTask(originalTask As Task, token As CancellationToken) As Task
    Using internalCts As New CancellationTokenSource()
        Using combinedCts As CancellationTokenSource = CancellationTokenSource.CreateLinkedTokenSource(token, internalCts.Token)
            Try
                Dim cancellationTask As Task = Task.Delay(-1, combinedCts.Token)
                Await Task.WhenAny(originalTask, cancellationTask)
                token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()
            Finally
                internalCts.Cancel()
            End Try
        End Using
    End Using
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks for the correction. I thought that without the ContinueWith continuation, the `WhenAny` won't be triggered, thinking it was only triggered if a Task completes to Completed state.